# Is it possible to register a Java application as backup software on Windows systems?

Tags: java, windows, backup

I'm working on a backup program which I'll be using on all our home devices. I'm currently writing this application in Java. My question is if there's any possible way to register this Java application as backup software on Windows based systems.

As far as I know, Windows has a feature that let anti-virus programs register them selves as anti-virus program in Windows. This allows the owner of the computer to select which anti-virus program to use, also, this gives the anti-virus program all permissions needed. And since windows knows a valid 3th party anti-virus program is used, it won't ask the user to enable Windows Defender or any other 3th party program.

Windows also ask the user to back up the users computer once in a while, if no recent back up is available. The question I'm having is if there's any possibility to register a Java application as backup software, so Windows know this program is used to back up the computer, and also to stop windows from showing these back up messages. And of course, if there's a possibility, how this could be done. Is there anyone that could help me with the issue I'm having?

I asked a similar question for Linux and Mac OS X systems here:
[Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246514/is-it-possible-to-register-a-java-application-as-backup-software-on-linux-system) and
[Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246571/is-it-possible-to-register-a-java-application-as-backup-software-on-mac-os-x-sys)

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to use a JNI library.

Comment: Do you have an example available that shows me how this could be done? Thanks in advance!